# How can I configure GRUB2 to boot into windows first rather than ubuntu?

Tags: grub

I need to configure grub to boot into windows XP before Ubuntu, and then hold the grub screen for ~3 seconds.

Could somebody help me do this from the Ubuntu CLI?

Answer (score 3):

you need to have windows as the first option - quite simply edit /etc/default/grub to have windows first, make sure GRUB_TIMEOUT is not commented out and has a value of 3 and save it. then run sudo update-grub

[full docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#/boot/grub/grub.cfg) here for more info